# Program in Java to list all the four digit numbers that have individual sum of 7

Tags: java, sum, addition

Program in Java to list all the four digit numbers that have individual sum of 7. ie.list the numbers from 0000 to 9999 that getting the sum of each of the four digits as 7.

Eg: 7171 is a four digit number and the sum of each of the four digit is as 7+1+7+1 = 16 and then 1+6 = 7.So this type of numbers should be listed.

I wrote a code,but its not working.Code is as follows:

```
public class Add 
{
    double i,s,n=0;
    void method()
    {
        for(i=0000; i<=9999; i++)
        {
            for(n=i;n>0;n/=10)
            {
                s=s+(n%10);

            }
            while(s>9)
            {
                for(n=s;n>0;n/=10)
                {
                    s=s+(n%10);
                }

            }
            if(s==7)
            {
                System.out.println("i");
            }
        }
     }



public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Add ob=new Add();
        ob.method();
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: either add your error message or show what is wrong with the output

Comment: Take paper and a pencil and try the code you've written with a number that's not working as expected. You'll learn a lot more than by asking us.

Comment: There is no errors, but no output.

Comment: Manu I am here after what you said.Anyway thanks

Comment: Check the statement part of your for instructions, n/10 is not doing what you think it does. Hint: it's a side effect free instruction.

Comment: zeros are of no significance to the algorithm so you might as well do 1 - 9999 instead of 0001

Comment: @Dragos.Cojocari Where do you see "n/10"? I can only see "n/=10" which has side effects.

Comment: My bad, I've misread the code.

Comment: Are the numbers 0-999 really 4 digit numbers?

Comment: I'm immediately drawn to the loop `while (s > 9)`, which needs `s` to get smaller for it to terminate.  But in the body we have `s = s + {something positive}`, so it looks like that loop will never terminate if the condition is initially true.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Yes, he needs to build a new total from `s` and then assign it to `s` when it's done. After that, the program will print a column of character `i`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the program you want:

```
public class SumDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=7; i<=9999; i+=9)
            System.out.printf("%04d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Sum of digits gives you the remainder of division by the number by 9. So just start with 7 and add 9 continuously and you'll get all such numbers.

Comment: You're providing a *different* code. How OP is supposed to learn from his mistakes by copying-pasting your ready solution? Please try to point at his mistakes and give him advice that will help him in the future.

Comment: Of course he provides *different* code. The same code doesn't work.

Comment: @TagirValeev: This isn't "help" this is "showing off". He needs help with fixing and understand his problem, not info about a math rule he doesn't know.

Comment: @Xabster I went back and forth on this answer for a minute, but I've concluded it's a good answer because it's useful to others. (Also helpful to the OP even if it doesn't fix their homework.) SO isn't supposed to be a debugging service, nor a help site. This isn't 'showing off', it's the ideal solution.

Comment: @Radiodef: Not a help site? Guess I misunderstood what this site is about.

Comment: this answer provides a very elegant and efficient answer to the question, along with an explanation. I certainly learned something from this answer.

Comment: @Xabster Primarily a knowledge base. The tour calls it a "library".

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little bit old, but it can help some others.

```
public class Add {

    int sum(String val)
    {
        int num=0,temp=0;
        int count=val.length();
        temp=count;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {                    
            temp--;
            char k=val.charAt(i);
            num += Character.getNumericValue(k);
            int p=String.valueOf(num).length();
            if(p>1&&temp==0)
            {
               count=p;
               i=-1;
               val=String.valueOf(num);
               num=0;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
       Add a=new Add();
       for(int k=0;k<9999;k++)
       {
           if(a.sum(String.valueOf(k))==7)
                System.out.println("Numbers are"+k);
       }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

Sum the each digits and the sum is greater than 10, again sum it .

```
public class Add {

public void calculate(int value) {
    for (int index = 1; index <= value; index++) {
        int i = index;
        int sum=0;
        int summation = 0;
        sum = computeDigits(i, sum);
        summation = computeDigits(sum, summation);

        if (summation == 7) {
            System.out.println(index);
        }
    }
}

private int computeDigits(int i, int sum) {
    while(i>9) {
        sum += i%10;
        i = i/10;
    }
    sum += i;
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Add ob = new Add();
    ob.calculate(1000);
}
```

}